# .NET Core DI - disposing of Singleton service in Console App

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, singleton, console-application

I've got this small console app for which I decided to wire up Microsoft's DI so it will care of dependencies for me. I don't have that much of a scopes, but rather transient and singleton services.

The problem is, it doesn't dispose singleton services. Maybe it's because it doesn't know when I'm done with it? Maybe because of some other reason.

Here's code of my static class handling injection (obviously in final app it's a bit more complex)

```
public static class ServiceInjector
{
    static IServiceProvider _services;

    static Stack<IServiceScope> _scopeStack;

    static IServiceProvider _provider => _scopeStack.NullPeek()?.ServiceProvider ?? _services;

    public static void Configure()
    {
        var svcCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        svcCollection.AddSingleton<ISampleSingletonService, SampleSingletonService>();

        _services = svcCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        _scopeStack = new Stack<IServiceScope>();
    }

    public static T GetService<T>()
    {
        return _provider.GetService<T>();
    }

    public static void StartScope()
    {
        _scopeStack.Push(_services.CreateScope());
    }

    public static void KillAllScopes()
    {
        while(_scopeStack.TryPop(out IServiceScope scope))
        {
            scope.Dispose();
        }

        _services = null; // I also tried to convince GC to clean it up and force Dispose. Nope.
    }
}
```

In `Program.Main` I call `ServiceInjector.Configure()` method, then `ServiceInjector.StartScope()`, then do stuff (injecting services) and in the end (in `finally` block of global exception handler) I call `ServiceInjector.KillAllScopes()`, when I want for it all to clear up.
Obviously it's not enough because `Dispose()` of my `SampleSingletonService` is never called (`ISampleSingletonService` inherits from `IDisposable`).

It's a problem because I use ILoggerProvider (from another `Microsoft.Extensions.` package) which caches stuff and flushes it to file each few seconds. If global exception handler finds some exception, I log it and want it to be flushed to disk, then exit the app. Without `Dispose` being called, app closes before last message can be flushed, so I loose that message.

I could obviously just halt the app for time longer than needed to flush to make sure it gets done, but let's just say it's not perfect solution.

I tried somehow disposing/cleaning/closing root `IServiceProvider`, but it doesn't inherit from `IDisposable` and I none of the available methods seem to be cleaning up mess created by it.

I also tried setting `_service` to null and calling `GC.Collect()`, but Garbage Collector seemed to not being interested in helping me ;)

For the demo purpose I created minimalistic reproduction app, which shows the issue (message from `Dispose` method of sample service is never logged): https://github.com/domints/DotnetDISingletonDisposingPoC

Thanks for any idea on how to resolve that problem.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines

Comment: @apocalypse I've seen it, but the thing is they use HostBuilder for it which somehow manages the lifetime of ServiceProvider. I created ServiceProvider myself (with use of `BuildServiceProvider` method), so this scenario didn't quite worked well for me.

Comment: Host builder was designed for scenarios like this. It is good to use it instad of creating custom logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke Dispose on _services field.
When disposing a scope, only scoped services will be disposed, but not singletons.

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
// configure services
using var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
using var serviceScope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
```

Comment: That was true, but the thing was, _services field was IServiceProvider, which does not contain IDisposable. That's what threw me off. 
Nonetheless, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, and the culprit. After relooking into this question, and the docs and the code I noticed `svcCollection.BuildServiceProvider()` doesn't return `IServiceProvider`, but `ServiceProvider`, which implements both `IServiceProvider` and `IDisposable`.

So changing my field to:

```
static ServiceProvider _services;
```

gave me access to Dispose() method and I could gracefully tell ServiceProvider I do not need him anymore so he can clean up after himself.

Link to docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectioncontainerbuilderextensions.buildserviceprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions_BuildServiceProvider_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Boolean_

Just as a note, it works the same way in .NET Core 3.1 and 5.0, can't assure for others, but I believe it would be the same for at least up to 2.2.